# Removing file extension with Rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently trying to do some url rewriting. I have made some progress but I can't seem to get this to remove the file extension.

The url it outputs current looks like:
article-install-apache-on-linux.php

I would like it to look like:
article-install-apache-on-linux/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^article-(.*).php$ ./article_show_friendly.php?url=$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `.php` from the first part and add an optional slash `/?`. Also, change `(.*)` to `(.+)` to ensure 1 or more characters.

```
RewriteRule ^article-(.+)/?$ /article_show_friendly.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Also added the `L` flag on the end to ensure rewriting stops at that point.